# How to use android P in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using android studio 3.1 and wondering how can I use android version P as `compile` and `target SDK` in my app.

Every time we just increment sdk number but now its showing as api `P` in SDK Manager

So my question is how can I use letter P for android P in place of number in both compile and target SDK.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the documentation I found that now we need to use string in single quotes by android platform name like given below

Setting compile sdk as Android P

```
compileSdkVersion 'android-P'
```

Setting target sdk as Android P

```
targetSdkVersion 'P'
```

And yes for using support libraries we can now use version 28 but its only available as Alpha

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
```

For more details go through this link of documentation [Set Up Android P sdk](https://developer.android.com/preview/setup-sdk)